# Why doesn't UWP WebView AddWebAllowedObject work?

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, uwp

I'm trying to use the WebView's AddWebAllowedObject method but, at runtime, an error is returned when is invoked the function that uses it. Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Notes: Dial class is contained in runtime project.

```
    [AllowForWeb]
    public sealed class Dial
    {
        public void Greet()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hello!");
        }
    }
```

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void WebView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            wv.NavigateToString("" +
                "<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                "<script>function hi() { dial.Greet(); }</script>" +
                "</head>" +
                "<body>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>"
            );
        }

        private void WebView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
        {
            wv.AddWebAllowedObject("dial", new Dial());
        }

        private async void WebView_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
        {
            await wv.InvokeScriptAsync("hi", new string[] {}); // Error 0x80020101
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that "Debug.Writeline()" won't work in JavaScript.  Try changing "Greet()" to return a string instead, and then have your "hi()" function call alert(dial.Greet()).  Also, I think you should call InvokeScriptAsync() like this: InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "'hi()" })

Comment: the solution is in the accepted answer. Thanks anyway for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By testing, you need to call the Greet() method of Dial class in lowercase in your html content as in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.addweballowedobject?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_AddWebAllowedObject_System_String_System_Object_).

```
private void WebView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    wv.NavigateToString("" +
        "<html>" +
        "<head>" +
        "<script>function hi() { dial.greet(); }</script>" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body>" +
        "</body>" +
        "</html>"
    );
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you, I spent an afternoon on the documentation without realizing the changed notation. Maybe they should highlight it more?